# Convert JSON feed to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, sbjson

Where `JSON_CATEGORY_DATA_URL_STRING` is my feed URL, which returns fine as:

```
[
    {
        "group":"For Sale",
        "code":"SSSS"
    },
    {
        "group":"For Sale",
        "category":"Wanted",
        "code":"SWNT"
    }
]
```

I cannot seem to get a nice `NSDictionary` (or `NSArray`) out of the following code:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)downloadJSON
{

NSDictionary *json_string;
NSString *dataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", JSON_CATEGORY_DATA_URL_STRING];
NSLog(@"%@",dataURL);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataURL]];    
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

json_string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSDictionary *json_dict = (NSDictionary *)json_string;
NSLog(@"json_dict\n%@",json_dict);
    NSLog(@"json_string\n%@",json_string);

return json_string;
}
```

I've read many posts on this, but am not getting it.

Comment: Also FWIW, JSONValue just returns null?

Comment: Well... turns out it was a bad feed. Original code was fine (even before rewriting 6 times and posting here).

Answer (score 101):

With IOS5 you can use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization) for serializing the JSON.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted is a writing option for use in writeJSONObject:, if you use it in this context you'll get the effect of NSJSONReadingMutableContainers applied to the read.

Comment: I have used the same
`NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
//    NSString *strJsonRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dicJsonRequest = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&convertError];`
It converts string successfully but for dicationary it is not converted to json format

Comment: Error is also null.what is wrong with this line.I have copy pasted your code

Comment: Sure that your JSON is written after standards?

Answer (score 8):

You can't just cast a string as a dictionary and expect it to parse the JSON. You must use a JSON parsing library to take that string and convert it into a dictionary.

Comment: For a list of JSON libraries for Objective-C, take a look at http://cocoaobjects.com/?s=json

Answer (score 2):

I made a class that makes this task easier. It uses iOS 5's NSJSONSerialization. Clone it from github [here](https://github.com/oscarvgg/JsonToDictionary).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSON parser. here is the edited code

```
+ (NSDictionary *)downloadJSON
{

NSDictionary *json_string;
NSString *dataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", JSON_CATEGORY_DATA_URL_STRING];
NSLog(@"%@",dataURL);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataURL]];    
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

json_string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
//JSONValue is a function that will return the appropriate object like dictionary or array depending on your json string.
NSDictionary *json_dict = [json_string JSONValue];
NSLog(@"json_dict\n%@",json_dict);
    NSLog(@"json_string\n%@",json_string);

return json_dict;
}
```

this should be the code to get the NSDictionary. but you json string is an array so instead use .

```
+ (NSArray *)downloadJSON
{

NSDictionary *json_string;
NSString *dataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", JSON_CATEGORY_DATA_URL_STRING];
NSLog(@"%@",dataURL);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataURL]];    
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

json_string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSArray *json_dict = [json_string JSONValue];
NSLog(@"json_dict\n%@",json_dict);
    NSLog(@"json_string\n%@",json_string);

return json_dict;
}
```

Edit:
you need to use JSON.framework to call JSONValue method.
also you need to return `json_dict` instead of `json_string` as `json_string` is of `NSString` type and not `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`.
and dont autorelease it, as it is your class variable

Comment: even as NSArray I still get json_dict null. Also, warning "NSArray (or NSDict) may not respond to JSONValue"

Comment: did you import `JSON parser` in your header file.

Comment: yes i know what you are doing wrong check out my edited answer.

Comment: To point out the obvious, json_string is declared as an NSDictionary *, but you say json_string is of NSString type.

Answer (score 0):

create method to fetchjson data.Pass your url in urlwithstring.

```
-(void)fetchjsondata
{
     NSString *login= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your url string"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"----%@", login);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[login stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //-- Get request and response though URL
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   if (data) {
                                       dic_property= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                                       NSLog(@"%@", dic_property);
                                       NSLog(@"counts=%d",[[dic_property objectForKey:@"Data"]count]);



                                   }
                                   else {
                                       NSLog(@"network error, %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
                                   }
                               });

                           }];

}
```

call fetchjsonmethod in anywhere.

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchdata) toTarget:self withObject:nil];