# I send some data to a webservice, it returns some JSON as NSData. How to convert to Dict?(iOS 4.3)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I send some credentials to a web-service.

I can get the responce as NSData or as an NSString.

Whats the simpleist way to convert the (NSData or NSString)JSON to a NSDictionary so I can process it?

Building for iOS4.3
Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: **First duplicate:** `NSData` to `NSString` => [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411965/converting-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-objective-c). **Second duplicate:** "JSON" to `NSDictionary` => [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038371/convert-json-feed-to-nsdictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download SBJsonParser Framework using the link, http://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads and add required classes to your project (SBJsonParser.h).

Import SBJsonParser.h and use the following code,

```
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

     //dictionary with name,id
     NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];  

     //name array                
      NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for (NSMutableDictionary *dic in jsonObject){

      [nameArray addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"name"]];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 5.0 and on you can use `NSJSONSerialization`, docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There is a good tutorial on how to use it, [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kURLString,self.chapter,self.page];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];


NSDictionary* result = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Result"];
```

Comment: What lib is the method JSONValue from?

Comment: You have to add JSON classes in your project and for this download it from gitHub and then #import "JSON.h" in your required class where you want to parse data.

Answer (score 0):

I use SBJson

```
NSArray *arrObj = (NSArray*)[[JsonParser sharedJsonParser] getObjectsFromJsonString:responseString];
```

response string is a JSON string here