# Parse JSON - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I'm new with json, and I need your help please.

I received JSON string like this :

```
{"network":
   {
   "network_id":111,
   "name":"test name",
   "city":"test city",
   "country":"test country",
   "description":"test desc"
   }
}
```

How I can handle this string and split key/value in order to use them in my view ?

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {    
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.responseData = nil;

//*********** How I can parse responseString *********//

[networkIDLabel setText:@"ADD THE VALUE"];
[nameLabel setText:@"ADD THE VALUE"];


    [responseString release];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/) on JSON parsing,.

Comment: Take a look to this question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038371/convert-json-feed-to-nsdictionary

Comment: Thanks Moonkid, the question is for array, and my string is not an array, can you help me please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in iOS App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530173/how-to-parse-json-in-ios-app)

Comment: @Vivek12 : all examples that I have viewed are already for arrays .. and what was received is not an array :(

Comment: Please close this, this have been already asked so many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective-c json can be represnted as Dictionary

```
-(void)getData:(NSData*)response{

 // You have to include the SBJSON or else you can also use the NSJSONSerialization

 //NSDictionary *jsonData          =           [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&erro];

SBJSON *parse                               =           [[SBJSON alloc]init];

NSString *jsonString                        =           [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response
                                                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSDictionary *jsonData                      =           [parse objectWithString:jsonString error:&erro];
NSDictionary *insideData                          =           [jsonData objectForKey:@"network"];

if(![insideData isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{

        NSString *data1         =       [insideData objectForKey:@"network_Id"];

         NSString *data2         =       [insideData objectForKey:@"name"];


 }

}
```

Comment: You have nested json or can say nested Dictionary so i edited my answer according yo your json

Comment: Thank you naveen :) .. I know that the question seems easy, but I don't familiar with NSDictionary so I can't solve it .. thank you again :))

Comment: I can print data1 on console, but I cannot used it with labels !! [label setText:[insideData objectForKey:@"network_Id"]]; then I have a crash :(

Comment: -[NSDecimalNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a5e530
2012-07-18 10:00:53.876 OAuthExample[839:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a5e530'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1400022 0x1591cd6 0x1401cbd 0x1366ed0 0x1366cb2 0x18a0ff 0x1b3d5 0xa4da49 0xa4be84 0xa4cea7 0xa4be3f 0xa4bfc5 0x990f5a 0x39d3a39 0x3aa0596 0x39ca120 0x3aa0117 0x39c9fbf 0x13d494f 0x1337b43 0x1337424 0x1336d84 0x1336c9b 0x12e97d8 0x12e988a 0x4a626 0x5932 0x28a5)

Comment: - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {    
    [connection release];
    
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *dic = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[dic objectForKey:@"network"] objectForKey:@"network_id"]); // works perfectly !
    [networkIDLabel setText:[[dic objectForKey:@"network"] objectForKey:@"network_id"]]; // crash my app !!

 self.responseData = nil;}

Comment: [networkIDLabel setText:[[dic objectForKey:@"network"] objectForKey:@"network_id"]]; dont do like this try this NSString *networkId = [dic objectForKey:@"network_ID"]; [networkIDLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",networkId]];

Comment: OMG !! [networkIDLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dic objectForKey:@"network"] objectForKey:@"network_id"]]]; // it's worked without crashing !! Thanks again Naveen :))

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 5 and later, you can parse the response data directly with NSJSONSerialization:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData …];
```

If you want to support earlier versions of iOS, you can use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/).

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, and yes I want to support earlier versions