# Parse encode custom error response

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nserror

In my Parse cloud code, I have custom errors like this

```
response.error({ 
    "Error" : "DEAL EXPIRED",
    "Title" : "Sorry!",
    "Message" : "This deal is expired :(",
    "Action" : "Ok"
});
```

Because I want to show a UIAlertView, but I have a problem to read the dictionary. My code in app is:

```
NSDictionary *errorDictionary = [error userInfo];

if ([[errorDictionary objectForKey:@"Error"] isEqualToString:@"DEAL EXPIRED"]) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[errorDictionary objectForKey:@"Title"]]
         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[errorDictionary objectForKey:@"Message"]]
         delegate:nil
         cancelButtonTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[errorDictionary objectForKey:@"Action"]]
         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

The log of errorDictionary is:

```
{"Error":"DEAL EXPIRED","Title":"Sorry!","Message":"This deal is expired :(","Action":"Ok"}
```

Thank you

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The code don't enter in the if statement. Maybe the dictionary must be parsed

Comment: What happens if you do `NSLog(@"the error is: %@",[errorDictionary objectForKey:@"Error"]);` before the `if` statement?

Comment: the log you print certainly looks like a JSON string rather than an `NSDictionary` instance...

Comment: @Wain Yes, most likely

Comment: so check the class. `NSError` `userInfo` should be a dictionary...

Comment: errorDictionary is [error userInfo];

Answer (score 0):

Because the printout of the string is null, it means that your `if` statement will always be false.  Therefore `[error userInfo]` is not an `NSDictionary` object.   You need to convert the JSON string to a `dictionary` before you can use it as a `dictionary`.

Here is an example if it is an `NSData` object.

```
NSDictionary * errorDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[error userInfo] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

[Here is the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithStream:options:error:) if it is a `NSInputStream` object.

There is more information on JSON to NSDictionary conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038371/convert-json-feed-to-nsdictionary).