# How to add entire JSON response into a NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm a new iOS developer I want to add my JSON response object into a NSDictionary, which is declared globally. I paste my code, so anyone easily understand how i got my response object.

```
[manager POST:strUrl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:@"TRUE"]) {
//Here I want this
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON feed to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038371/convert-json-feed-to-nsdictionary)

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: "It didn't work" is not very helpful to understand your problem. Please share more of your code and explain what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, that is:

```
[dictManagement addEntriesFromDictionary:responseObject];
```

Here `dictManagement` is an `NSMutableDictionary`.